# error in FOR IN loop

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I am trying to run the below function for the array quandlURLs in a for in loop. I am getting an error in line "loadDataFromURL", saying :can not convert value of type [String] to expected argument of type 'Sting'. Can somebody please tell me what I am missing here. Thanks!!

```
class func getDataFromQuandlWithSuccess(success: ((Quandl: NSData!) -> Void)) {
 let quandlGold = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/LBMA/GOLD.json?auth_token=xyzDP7Cj-2F_Jss7sYHf&rows=1"        
quandlURLs = [quandlGold, quandlSilver,quandlPlatinum,quandlPalladium]
    var index: Int
    var urlData = [String]()
    for index in quandlURLs {
        loadDataFromURL(NSURL(string: quandlURLs[index])!, completion:{(data, error) -> Void in
            //2
            if let urlData[index] = data {
                //3
                success(Quandl: urlData[index])
                //below worked and showed raw data
                //print("Successful \(urlData)")

            }
        })

    }
}
```

here is the loadDataFromURL function

```
class func loadDataFromURL(url: NSURL, completion:(data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

// Use NSURLSession to get data from an NSURL
let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if let responseError = error {
    completion(data: nil, error: responseError)
  } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
      let statusError = NSError(domain:"com.raywenderlich", code:httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP status code has unexpected value."])
      completion(data: nil, error: statusError)
    } else {
      completion(data: data, error: nil)
    }
  }
})

loadDataTask.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight the error line please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do here is change `for index in quandlURLs` to `for index in 0..<quandlURLs.count`

There was also an issue with `if let urlData[index] = data`, because you can't use optional binding with an array, you need to define a new value, so go `if let urlDataEntry = data`, in which case your urlIndex array should be of type NSData.

You also don't need the `var index: Int` line. Int is inferred when using the for in loop on the ..< function that creates an Int array, and the index variable is usable throughout the for loop.

For example:

```
class func getDataFromQuandlWithSuccess(success: ((Quandl: NSData!) -> Void)) {
    let quandlGold = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/LBMA/GOLD.json?auth_token=xyzDP7Cj-2F_Jss7sYHf&rows=1"        
    quandlURLs = [quandlGold, quandlSilver,quandlPlatinum,quandlPalladium]
    var urlData = [NSData]()
    for index in 0..<quandlURLs.count {
        loadDataFromURL(NSURL(string: quandlURLs[index])!, completion:{(data, error) -> Void in
            //2
            if let urlDataEntry = data {
                //3
                urlData[index] = urlDataEntry
                success(Quandl: urlDataEntry)
                //below worked and showed raw data
                //print("Successful \(urlData)")

            }
         })

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment - unfortunately, the error is still the same. I should have mentioned that the array is built out of  weblinks, e.g.
     let quandlGold = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/LBMA/GOLD.json?auth_token=xyzDP7Cj-2F_Jss7sYHf&rows=1"
I added this to the above comment for further clarification.

Comment: Would you be able to include the whole class? loadDataFromURL appears to be another function in your class and I can't test the code without it.

Comment: Hi James, I have added the loadDataFromURL above. Thank you for looking at this! Cheers

Comment: I've had another look, and seen what the problem is. The for in loop sets index to the string value from the array, so when you subscript (i.e. quandlURLs[index]) you would be doing so with a string value, when it wants an Int. I've updated my answer to show

Comment: Hi James, well spottet. I now get a "Invalid Pattern" error in line if let urlData[index] = data {..........Would you mind having another look at this?

Comment: I noticed that but forgot to include it in the answer. I'll take a look.

Comment: I've found the problem and included it in my answer

Comment: Thank you for solving this! I however have now no idea how to call this function, since it is now converting this into a huge JSON dataset.  I want to now load the data for every index into an array for that particular index.